# setCompoundDrawables not displaying icon

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-edittext, drawable

Currently,
I am implementing a Fragment to change the user password. To do so the user has to confirm his password. When both password's match I want to display an icon inside the EditText. to verify this while the user is typing I implemented the following function:

```
 private fun EditText.afterTextChanged(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Doing so I can use `editText.afterTextChanged{...}` to compare the values of the two editTexts. When both values match I am currently trying to display the icon with the following code:

```
val icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
        resources,
        R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_24,
        null
    )

    icon?.setBounds(
        0, 0,
        icon.intrinsicWidth,
        icon.intrinsicHeight
    )
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icon, null)
```

Unfortuantly this is not working. I already tried using `setCompoundDrawables` instead of `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` but it makes no difference. Furthermore, I tried using `R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_24` directly in the function, but it is not working either.

Does somebody have an idea what's wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite the previous Drawable before setting the new Drawable.

The description of the Android document about the function is as follows:

```
Sets the Drawables (if any) to appear to the left of, above, to the right of, and below the text. Use null if you do not want a Drawable there. The Drawables' bounds will be set to their intrinsic bounds.

Calling this method will overwrite any Drawables previously set using setCompoundDrawablesRelative(Drawable, Drawable, Drawable, Drawable) or related methods.
```

So you need to first set Drawable to null and then try again.

```kotlin
val icon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
        resources,
        R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_24,
        null
    )

    icon?.setBounds(
        0, 0,
        icon.intrinsicWidth,
        icon.intrinsicHeight
    )
    editText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null) //add this line code
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icon, null)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now everything works as it should.